# This Java program does not display the expected deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Along the lines of a deadlock example given in Oracle java documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html), I wanted to simulate a situation in my country. When a pair of trains are running in the opposite directions, the train that reaches an intermediate station first gives a "key" to the waiting staff (The train does not stop, but the engine driver throws a big pouch with key to the platform. The staff waiting there would collect it). It is then collected by the other train reaching the intermediate station later. If both the trains reach the station at the same time, then it would result in a deadlock. So, I wrote the following code to illustrate this:

```
public class Deadlock
{
    static class Express
    {
        private final String name;
        public Express(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        public synchronized void reached(Express laterTrain)
        {
            System.out.println(this.name + " is earlier than " +
                laterTrain.getName());
            giveKey(laterTrain);
        }
        public synchronized void giveKey(Express laterTrain)
        {
            System.out.println(name + " gives key to " +
                laterTrain.getName());
        }
    }
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Express Rajdhani1 = new Express("Rajdhani ONE");
        final Express Rajdhani2 = new Express("Rajdhani TWO");
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Rajdhani1.reached(Rajdhani2);
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Rajdhani2.reached(Rajdhani1);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I was expecting an output like:

```
Rajdhani ONE is earlier than Rajdhani TWO
Rajdhani TWO is earlier than Rajdhani ONE
```

and the program hanging there forever. But, I got the following output and the execution promptly returned to commandline. How?

```
Rajdhani ONE is earlier than Rajdhani TWO
Rajdhani TWO is earlier than Rajdhani ONE
Rajdhani ONE gives key to Rajdhani TWO
Rajdhani TWO gives key to Rajdhani ONE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't run your code, but you are doing things differently than in your linked example code: you are calling the `giveKey` on the wrong object in the `reached()` function.

According to the referenced example it should be:

```
// bower.bowBack(this);
laterTrain.giveKey(this);
```

but you are calling:

```
// this.bowBack(bower);
this.giveKey(laterTrain);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the howler. I applied your correction and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you calling giveKey method you are passing different object to that method. Shouldn't you be passing the object on which the method is called ?

You should be pass "this" to giveKey function and check out the output. It should work as per documentation link provided by you.